# Responsive Form Inside Div With Responsive Background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to add a text input and button to a div with a responsive background image using bootstrap. I'm easily able to make each responsive on their own however not together.

I believe this is due to the positions I've given them. I'm looking for a way for them to scale together no matter the screen size.

CSS:

```
 <style>
            #optin-bg{
                max-width: 799px;
                min-height: 310px;
                height: auto;
                background-image: url(http://placehold.it/799x310.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size:contain;
                background-position:center;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #optin-form{
                position:absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 10%;
            }

            #email-input{
                margin-bottom:10px;
            }
        </style>
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" id="optin-bg">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" id="optin-form">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-input" placeholder="Email">
                <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="email-submit" >Submit</button>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f07y6xkx/

Comment: Just to be clear: You want your input and button to scale? I'm afraid that will need some javascript because you'll also need to scale your `font-size`

Comment: @mmgross Correct. I thought bootstrap might have some sort of media queries that take care of the scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue with multiple media queries and resetting the size/position of the form. Easy, somewhat messy, fix.

For example:

```
    @media(min-width: 768px){
        #optin-bg {
            background: url("optin_image_2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0/100% auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            min-height: 310px;
            max-width: 550px;
        }
        #optin-form{
            width: 40%;
            top: 120px;
            left: 5px;
        }
    }
    @media(min-width: 992px){
        #optin-bg {
            min-height: 310px;
            max-width: 699px;
        }
        #optin-form{
            width: 30%;
            top: 150px;
            left: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media(min-width: 1200px){
        #optin-bg {
            min-height: 310px;
            max-width: 799px;
        }
        #optin-form{
            top: 175px;
            left: 10px;
        }

    }
```